# NR Intercell Interference Modeling

Tags: matlab

When I read the example
[NR Intercell Interference Modeling](https://www.mathworks.com/help/5g/ug/nr-intercell-interference-modelling.html) in Matlab, I cannot find the process of interference. Can anyone tell me which function can calculate the interference?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ZaellixA in cant find the process or function that calculate the interference in this example